# I have modified my /etc/sudoers to execute any command with out a password but it didn't work and it still prompted a password request

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sudo, users

## Question

I have modified my /etc/sudoers (by visudo) to allow myself to execute any command with out a password but it didn't work.

All of similar questions don't work for me.

I still have to input my password when I'm using sudo.

### My username and groups

```
❯ id -nG
guo network power libvirt autologin rfkill users video storage lp audio wheel sudo
```

### System

```
❯ uname -a
Linux lead-inspiron 6.2.1-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun, 26 Feb 2023 03:39:23 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### My /etc/sudoers

```
❯ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

guo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I still couldn't `sudo` without inputing my password.

BTW, I'm not a native English speaker so i'm sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

With your `/etc/sudoers`, you should already have the user account `guo` authorized to run any command as any user without a password prompt,  three times over: since `guo` is a member of groups `wheel` and `sudo`, the line `guo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` will give `guo` exactly the same access as the line `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` combined with the membership in the `wheel` group, or as the line `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` combined with the membership in the `sudo` group.

But `sudo` is also configured to read the files in `/etc/sudoers.d`, and the **last** rule that matches the command will apply. So there must be some rule in `/etc/sudoers.d/*` that matches, and that rule apparently does not have the `NOPASSWD:` tag.

By running `sudo -l` as user `guo` (or `sudo -l -U guo` as any other user and providing a password if required) you can view all the `sudo` options and rules that will be applied to the user.

You should rearrange your `sudoers` rules so that one of the rules with the `NOPASSWD:` tag will be the **last** rule. For example:

```
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
# guo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL  # not needed as guo is a member of both wheel and sudo groups
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```